# Vector vs Vectors in spark

Tags: scala, apache-spark, vector

i am a newbie in Spark.
I am trying to read a text file that has data like:

> **timestamp id counter value**
>
> ---
>
> ```
> 00:01     1  c1     0.5
> 00:02     5  c3     0.3
> 00:03     1  c2     0.1
> 00:04     2  c2     0.13
> ```

and transform them to:

> **(id, array_of_counters):**
>
> ---
>
> ```
> (1, [ c1   c2 ])  
>     [ 0.5  0.1]
> ```

So, for every `id`, i create an `2d array`, which will have every counter and every value for that specific `id` in the text file.

I tried to do it with `Vectors` but i think that what is stored in them, must be double and that i cannot add two vectors, except the case they are breeze Vectors.

Then, i found out there is a data structure called just `Vector` but i can't find any details about it.

So, my question is what are the main differences between `Vector` and `Vectors` in `mllib`?

Code:

```
val inputRdd = sc.textFile(inputFile).map(x => x.split(","))
val data = inputRdd.map(y => (y(1), Vector(y(2), y(3)))).reduceByKey(_++_)
```

Comment: I believe OP is asking about spark's `Vector` type, and not scala's in-built collection.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think a `Vector` is necessary or appropriate for what it appears you are trying to do here (I could be wrong, we need more specifics on what you want to accomplish). The only way it makes sense is if there is a fixed number of *counters* (`c1`, `c2`, etc...) for each id. If you simply want a set of every id, with it's corresponding list of *counters* and values, try this (I'm assuming counters are unique to each `id`):

```
val data = inputRdd
  .map(y => (y(1).toLong, y(2), y(3).toDouble))
  .toDF("id", "counter", "value")
  .groupBy("id")
  .agg(collect_list(map($"counter", $"value")))
  .as[(Long, Seq[Map[String, Double]])]
  .map(r => (r._1, r._2.reduce(_++_)))
  //this results in a Dataset[(Long, Map[String, Double])]
```

A spark `ml.linalg.Vector` is basically an `Array[Double]`, and would require a fixed number of `counter` for every record. You could tranform from the `data` above into a vector by ordering the `Map[String, Double]` by it's `._1` and creating a `Vector` from it's `.values`.

[`ml.linalg.Vectors`](https://spark.apache.org/docs/2.3.0/api/scala/index.html#org.apache.spark.ml.linalg.Vectors$) is just a helper object with functions for creating `Vector` objects.

> Factory methods for org.apache.spark.ml.linalg.Vector. We don't use the name Vector because Scala imports scala.collection.immutable.Vector by default.

It's also worth noting that `mllib` is intended for the older RDD API while `ml` is intended for the newer Dataframe/Dataset API.

## Edit:  `RDD[(Long, Seq[(String, Double)])]`

```
val data = inputRdd
  .map(y => (y(1).toLong, Seq[(String, Double)]((y(2), y(3).toDouble))))
  .reduceByKey(_++_)
```

Comment: What i want is to have for every id, an array with its counters and values. And no, there is not a fixed number of counters for every id, but i am trying to create an algorithm from a paper, and in the paper there is an array for each id. Is there any other data structure without using Dataframe/Dataset API, for my case?

Comment: Does it have to be a `2d array` as posed in the question? To me an `RDD[(Long, Map[String, Double])]` seems to make the most sense...

Comment: The thing is that for every counter, there will be more than one values in each id, so i think map cannot work for this senario.

Comment: Understood, how about a `Seq[(String, Double)]` then?